# using Visual Studio 2017 missing arrow icon on debug mode while hovering a variable

Tags: visual-studio-2017

whenever I want to hover a variable or class in a debug mode, an arrow that previously appear when there is information inside that variable is now gone, sometimes it have the arrow, and sometimes it is gone, and while I expand it when the arrow is gone, my visual studio will be freeze and not responding.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional latest updates.

Anyone having a same issue? and how to solve this? What is the cause?

Thank you.

[Visual Studio 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yiTA.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be a bug in the new Version 15.3
The only solution I found, to get the icons back, is while debugging you have to watch a variable (right-click on variable and click "Add Watch").

Here is a link to the site, where I found this hint:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/71523/during-debug-datatips-are-missing-icons-and-tree-m.html

I hope they will fix this soon...